# How to view any User-Level Network Policies that have been applied?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have implemented a couple User-Level Network Policies, but really don't have a way to check to see which policy has been applied to which user. Is there a way to query Snowflake for this information?

Answer (score 2):

The functionality to access user-level network policies is not yet available through UI or SQL. However, you could use the workaround below.

```
USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;  -- or ACCOUNTADMIN role
SHOW USERS;
-- For each user listed:
SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE '%NETWORK_POLICY%' IN USER <username>;
```